# Does function inlining use more RAM or ROM? and what is effect on micro-controller's RAM?

Tags: c, embedded, inline

When I write an inline function in my code (a bare-metal code for stm32), I know that every time we call this inline function it is replaced with its definition this saves the overhead of a function calling i.e. save stack.

Now I am confused, between RAM and ROM usage of the inline function.

Can anyone please join memory usage of an inline function with RAM and ROM usage, especially in the context of a bare-metal code.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear as we don't the the specifics of your system but in general... When a function is inlined it will increase the size of your programs executable. So assuming your executable is stored in ROM, it will increase the amount of ROM memory used. On the other hand - when a function is inlined it will (typically) decrease the amount of stack memory used. However, since stack memory is preallocated you won't see any change in RAM usage but it may allow you to configure the system with smaller stacks and thereby save RAM.

Comment: @4386427 yes size of executable binary increase with use of inline, when we start execution binary moved from ROM to RAM (correct me here if wrong). If it is true, then RAM usage also increased. right?

Comment: It depends on your system. Some embedded systems do move the executable from ROM into RAM but other systems may execute directly from ROM. As I can't know how your system works I'm not able to post a real answer. To answer your question one needs to know the specifics about system but the general rule is: Inline will increase size of executable and reduce stack requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your linker will be able to generate a link map with a summary of ROM and RAM usage - you can build with and without inlining and see the result for yourself.

Inlining causes copies of the code to replace calls to a single copy of code, so by definition the code space (ROM in your case) is increased. It has little effect on RAM, although reduce stack usage by a small amount because no return address is required.  That is a run-time reduction and will not show in the link map.

It will only make a difference if your compiler chooses to apply the `inline` request. GCC for example will not do so at the -O0 (default) optimisation level, and even then may not do so in all circumstances, and may even in-line code that is not explicitly marked for inlining.

Your compiler may have a means to force inlining, but the `inline` keyword is not it - for example in GCC you would use the `__attribute__((always_inline))` function attribute.  However second guessing the compiler when it comes to what should and should not be inlined is generally a bad idea with a modern optimising compiler.  It will generally make better more holistic decisions on a code base of any significant size with no developer effort.

Comment: compiler may inline even without the `inline`

Answer (score -1):

If you run your code from the FLASH memory, the length of the code does not affect your RAM usage. The code will be longer of course if the function is inlined more than once (but it is not guaranteed by the 'inline' keyword).

Another question is the usage of the SRAM memory for the local variables storage. Usually it will be lower as inlining allows more aggressive optimizations (inline functions can be used only if the optimizations are on - otherwise they will not be inlined).

'inline' keyword is only a suggestion for the compiler, if you want to force the inlining you need to use the apripriate attribute or pragma - for gcc `__attribute__((always_inline))`